# Windows 2012 R2 FTP server IIS 8 Passive mode not working

Tags: ftp, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, passive-mode

I have set up an FTP Server on Windows Server 2012 R2 using IIS 8 and everything works fine except Passive Mode when connecting from client machines. How to fix it?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this has helped:
https://kb.plesk.com/en/128834

Specifically: Remove duplicated IP address from FTP Firewall Support in FTP site settings.

Turns out FTP Firewall Support is an option in two places - and it only needs to be in the general, server node, not site node. I removed the site one and viola!

More VERY helpful info I found on the way:

Setting up FTP: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server
There are more on Technet Microsoft but I can't paste more than 2 links here sadly.

Excellent Troubleshooting: Search on Youtube for "IIS FTP Troubleshooting-Week 48", videos by: DotNetSlackers. His videos from Week 44 cover FTP and are very good.